# Counting clique free graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, asymptotics

I'm looking for a reasonable but simple lower bounds or asymptotics for $S_n(k)$, the number of labelled graphs on $n$ vertices that contain no $k+1$-clique.
A rather weak lower bound is the number of connected graphs on $k$ vertices times the number of ways to choose $k$ vertices from $v$, but even this is quite messy.

---

Kolaitis, Prömel, and Rothschild showed in 1987 that $S_n(k)$ is asymptotically equal to the number of labelled graphs on $n$ vertices that are $k$-colourable (or $k$-partite).
J. Balogh et al. recently improved this, showing that nearly all $k$-free graphs are $k-1$-partite when $k$ is a slowly growing function of $n$.  (arXiv:1406.6961)
Finally, Prömel in 1987 showed that nearly all labelled graphs containing no $k$-clique are rigid.
However, these results do not seem to yield an explicit expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind: Mousset, Nenadov and Steger ([arXiv:1312.1143v3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1143)) showed that $S_n(k) = 2^{(1-1/k)n^2/2 + o(n^2/(k+1))}$, even when $k$ is a slowly growing function of $n$.  This extends a result of Erdős, Kleitman and Rothschild from 1976 ([preprint](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1976-03.pdf)) for fixed $k$.